# DWA 131 wireless adapter not working 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless

Please help me in troubleshooting the issue with my wireless USB adapter.

OS - Ubbuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Wireless adapter - DWA 131 nano USB adapter, HW Version - E1.

Issue:- USB stick is getting detected. I have installed below driver. But the issue still persists. Please find the screenshots to understand my current configuration...

---

Code:

```
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~/Desktop/DWA/Win7x86$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:64ad Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0042 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1058:0839 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I added a driver for this adapter to PPA. I have verified the inf file(driver package for Windows) and found the driver (rtl8192eu) is correct.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

Followed below steps also

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

I was following steps mentioned in following link (I am not allowed to post the link).. I am getting "Invalid driver!" message as mentioned below.

```
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~/Desktop/DWA/Win81x86$ sudo ndiswrapper -i Dnetrtwlanu.inf 
driver dnetrtwlanu is already installed
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~/Desktop/DWA/Win81x86$ sudo ndiswrapper -l
[COLOR=#ff0000]dnetrtwlanu : invalid driver!
```

I have received the driver for Linux from below link.

http://files.dlink.com.au/Products/D...r_v4.3.1.1.zip

Now I upgraded to 16.04 LTS to hope that my wireless adapter works. However no luck yet. Kindly help me resolve the issue..

I would really appreciate it.

---

The directory/file was removed & rebboted the system as suggested.

`code`
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -r dnetrtwlanu
[sudo] password for himansu: 
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -r dnetrtwlanu
couldn't delete /etc/ndiswrapper/dnetrtwlanu: No such file or directory

@Jeremy- Reboot after removing ndiswrapper driver, didn't resolve the issue. I have run the script & got the info generated. uploaded at below link. Kindly review & suggest. https://gist.github.com/hmsvigle/9e3d711375595152bc2cda2bf3ae6593

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `modinfo 8192eu | grep 3319` and also:  `sudo ndiswrapper-l` but only if the latter is now different from what you posted above following the installation of 16.04.

Comment: Edit to include results for `lspci -nnk |grep -iA3 net` as it might be easier to get the internal Intel wifi going

Comment: @Chili555 - himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$ modinfo 8192eu | grep 3319
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$ 
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -l
[sudo] password for himansu: 
dnetrtwlanu : invalid driver!

Comment: @Jeremy31 - My internal wifi hardware is not working properly. For which I have been using external wifi adapter. no o/p for A3. himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$ lspci -nnk |grep -i A3
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$

Comment: @Jeremy31 meant to say: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` What about your internal wireless is not working as expected?

Comment: Hi @chili555 - Yea, My internal wireless is not working. :( No o/p for the command. himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
himansu@himansu-Inspiron-5537:~$

Comment: It might help to remove ndiswrapper driver with `sudo ndiswrapper -r dnetrtwlanu`  Then reboot and if you still have issues see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) and edit the question to include the results

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31 - Once you get a chance to check my wifi info shared . Kindly help me suggest some work-around. Appreciate all your help. [Link] https://gist.github.com/hmsvigle/9e3d711375595152bc2cda2bf3ae6593

Comment: @chili555 - Kindly suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the ndiswrapper command was exactly correct. Please try:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -e dnetrtwlanu
```

Please post any errors or warnings and we'll try to fix them.

Next, I don't believe the rtl8192eu-dkms package covers your exact device; let's remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge rtl8192eu-dkms
```

Finally, I believe the Mange package from github *is* correct. Just to be on the safe side, let's get a fresh clone:

```
rm -r rtl8192eu-linux-driver
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working. As before, post any errors and we'll try to fix them. A few warnings are probably harmless.

Comment: Now It worked fine. after I removed the package - rtl8192eu-dkms and recompiled freshly downloaded copy. Thanks a lot for all the help. I really appreciate it. :)