# internet is slow with D-Link DWA-131 wireless adapter

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I am facing this issue recently instantly with my D-Link DWA-131 wireless adapter. Mine is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My adapter was working perfectly since past 3 years. All of a sudden since 2 days, I am facing the issue of slow internet. With the adapter, speed becomes less than 10MB/s. Without the adapter, It shows 80-90MB/s.

I am suspecting some issue is with the D-Link adapter / the driver. Also I cant rely on my inbuilt adapter as it doesn't work always & cant afford to  replace motherboard.

Every time I reboot my laptop, I get this exception. Is this somehow causing any issue !!
Exception:
**[0.056088] ipmi:dmi : Invalid offset : 0**

kindly please help....
Please find results:-

`himansu@master: sudo rfkill list all
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

Uploaded the result of wireless-info at the link  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DhpjzZpd2k/

---

himansu@master: ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc terbin.com 9999

Results saved in "/home/himansu/wireless-info.txt".

Results also archived in "/home/himansu/wireless-info.tar.gz", as they exceed the 19.5 kB size limit for ".txt" attachments on the Ubuntu Forums.

himansu@master: nc terbin.com 9999
himansu@master:

I updated the details at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Sz3mtCbBKf/

Comment: @chilli555 Kindly help

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include results

Comment: @Jeremy31 Updated the question with required logs. Please check

Comment: @Jeremy31 Please let me know, If any other logs I need to share for troubleshooting.

Comment: Why are you forcing it to load rtl8192cu and using the `echo "2001 3319" | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id`  I would get rid of that, then do `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and reboot

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31, I made the changes. But still the same issue. My motherboard adapter is having issue. So I am using DWA-131 adapter as substitute. May be that was the reason to enforce to load the driver. The changes were done 2 years ago. So I dont recall. I am not sure, if there is issue with my hardware- DWA-131 adapter or the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a module built from source code on github

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
sudo dkms add rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31 After this, my laptop wifi is working but crashes randomly after few hours. Also my D-Link dwa-131 wifi adapter is not working at all. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Run `./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` post URL

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31,  I run the command. logs are updated in the question & output pasted at the link.

Comment: try `echo lp | sudo tee /etc/modules` remove that line from /etc/rc.local  then reboot.  Why is the internal Intel wifi not enabled?

Comment: The changes to /etc/modules & /etc/rc.local was done 2 years back, when I had issues with my internal wifi adapter. I guess, that was the reason, internal wifi was disabled & the external wifi driver was enabled for continuous connection.

Comment: I am not sure how that worked at all trying to use the rtl8192cu module to run a rtl8192eu chipset

Comment: steps implemented as per this... https://askubuntu.com/questions/910793/dwa-131-wireless-adapter-not-working-16-04-lts

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31 After performing the steps you suggested, the connection is working fine. I have not used extensively yet. I will update you on this. Thanks a lot for the help.